# URL type column issue in SharePoint List

Tags: publishing-site, column

I am using SharePiont Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have a list on a page, and one column in the list is URL type. Currently, when I click the link, the URL pointed destination page will be opened in current browser windows. How to make the page pointed by the URL open in a new browser window?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that is out of the box that will do this.  Your best bet is to used SP Designer and convert the list view WebPart into a data view WebPart.  Then you can edit the XSL and set the `target = _blank`.  At my work we developed a Advanced Links List WebPart which adds a target column to the list automatically and handles instances such as this as well as being able to display a links list as a treeview, menu or other type of control.

Comment: "convert the list view webpart into a data view webpart" -- can you show me how please?

Comment: Edit the page in SP Designer, right click on the list view webpart and click "Convert to XSLT Data View".

Answer (score 1):

This question is an "oldie but goldie" :-)

Andrew Connell has a more generic way of solving this using an "open in new window" field:
http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/SharepointLinksListOpenInNewWindow.aspx

Comment: I read through this solution, but find it is a little bit complex. Any easier solutions?

Comment: yeah its called google :-)
No seriously, if you google this you should find a lot of suggestions. Also in the article i linked, theres a couple of references.

Answer (score 1):

I would treat this as a training issue.  For a long time I've managed to segment my link clicking between open, open in new tab, open in new window.

Comment: "managed to segment my link clicking between open, open in new tab, open in new window." -- more details description about how to implement this?

Comment: Click a link - goes to the link in the same browser window
Right click, select Open Link in new window - Opens the link in a new window.
Right click, select Open Link in new tab - Opens the link in a new tab.

While it would be great if SharePoint had the extra granularity and configurability to handle this sort of thing everywhere I would be worried that it would bloat the code base and honestly it is hard to know what every user is going to want to do with it anyway.